# Is keeping (rolling back to) the previous version of a post justified after it was edited for a good reason?

Tags: discussion

The most [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/100003/8) revision of the [*What is a metaclass in Python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/1309352) is seemingly a complete rollback of the edit which was tended more towards conformance with the SO standards. The edit summary of the rollback states:

> This is not wikipedia. Please let the answer["question" I believe] with it's original human
>   writting style. We are not robots.

Does that amount to non-conformance? Or something similar?

I truly believe that question's a piece of gold. But the edits are meant to further polish and improve them. New language learner/explorers and likely-to-be-future or current community members, who are very likely to hit this fundamental question, will (sub)consciously try to imitate the style of it believing that it's SO standard straining the community to edit their posts, if they happen to imitate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very bluntly stated, no. If you don't like the idea of your posts getting edited and improved, this might not the be site for you. It's one of the site's most valuable features, and you will have to accept it, unless harm is done to your post.

I think George's edit was an improvement, cutting out some fluff. Would I personally do anything about this rollback? I'd say no. The post in its current form is not bad, and the situation is not something to get worked up over. Perhaps a moderator comment might suffice there, but not everything is worth a fight.